# What is the correct casing for a character's title?

Tags: style, naming

I'm currently writing some fiction about a lord and I'm struggling with when I should capitalise his title.

There are a number of circumstances.

When someone is referring to him or about him using his title:

> "Of course my lord."

When the title is used as part of his name:

> "Welcome Lord Smith."

Or in the third person:

> What did the lord say?

The pattern I've found is to only capitalise when the title is used as part of the character's proper name - Lord Smith. When used in place of his name I've not capitalised.

> "What did the young Lord say?"

Doesn't look right to me.

Is this approach correct? Is there a better rule to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have everything right except the last one, which should be

> "What did the young lord say?"

You're essentially following [AP style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/735/02/) for titles.

> Generally, capitalize formal titles when they appear before a person’s name, but lowercase titles if they are informal, appear without a person’s name, follow a person’s name or are set off before a name by commas. Also, lowercase adjectives that designate the status of a title. If a title is long, place it after the person’s name, or set it off with commas before the person’s name. Examples: President Bush; President-elect Obama; Sen. Harry Reid; Evan Bayh, a senator from Indiana; the senior senator from Indiana, Dick Lugar; former President George H.W. Bush; Paul Schneider, deputy secretary of homeland security.

Comment: Agreed.  Liath, you may be struggling because calling people "lord" is uncommon today, but think about how you use "sir" and I think you'll naturally do the right thing.